# issue with concatenated subs

Tags: vba

DISCLAIMER: I'm not a developer, just an average guy trying to use VBA on his own project. First time I post on stackoverflow so forgive me if I'm violating any unwritten community rule..

Hi all, I'm trying to have a bunch of subs running in sequence, so the next one starts only when the previous one has finished.

The problem is that excel keep on crashing during the execution, while if I run each sub manually they have no issue at all.

So far I have been using this method: First I have a mini sub that assigns value=1 to the global variable "oneclick", and then calls the first macro of the chain

then, in each sub there is a tiny piece just before the end:

```
sub macro1()

...macro code...

if oneclick=1 then
  call macro2
end if

end sub
```

and so on for all the subs until the final sub resets the oneclick variable to zero.

I have no idea why this keeps on crashing. I can see that actually none of these subs is really closing until the very end of the last one, would this hit any sort of code limitation? I would be actually happier to have a single master sub that directs the process instead of relying on a kludge like this! any suggestion?

EDIT:
oh wow already so many answers.. now I'm gonna try some of those. Answering some of your questions:

1) the crash is really something sudden, not even an error message, simply excel quits and reopens, in the same state as it was when the macro chain first started.

2) I agree with you guys that there should be a master sub calling the smaller ones, however last time I tried I got a series of problems because one macro needs to work on the results of the previous one and so on. How do you tell to vba to wait until the previous sub has ended?

Comment: What happens is you create a "call stack" and you utilise [Excel Memory](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3066990/memory-usage-in-the-32-bit-edition-of-excel-2013-and-2016) for each routine you have "open". Perhaps you are creating a large call stack that is overloading your Excel internal memory (RAM). Maybe look at trying to create less individual routines and combine them into one. If that still causes your Excel to crash perhaps it's your code, and not your lack of memory resource management.

Comment: @DeanDeVilliers Or instead of the current practice, calling routine 3 from within 2, call routine 3 from within routine 1. Allowing routine 2 to close.

Comment: Yes, @Luuklag, or that

Comment: You need to tell us what "crash" means here. Without that we can only guess

Comment: It is a good thing that you have split up the whole task in to smaller ones. You could now do what most programmers would do, create one 'main' sub, from which you call the present subs one after another. Thus you would only call the 'main' and that would take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

It is best if you don't chain the macros, but instead call them from another sub. This way you will have a clear way of understanding what you are doing, in what order.

```
Sub AllOfIt()
    macro1
    DoEvents

    macro2
    DoEvents

    macro3
End Sub

Sub macro1
    ...
End Sub

Sub macro2
    ...
End Sub

Sub macro3
    ...
End Sub
```

There is generally no need to worry about if something starts before the previous macro ended. That does not happen unless you do something like using `Application.OnTime`

Comment: tried this solution, but excel still crashes. All the individual subs run without a glitch, so I think that this structure is not exactly "neutral" when it comes to executing each macro as a completely "insulated" block.

Comment: @PaoloRomano - I added `DoEvents` to the code above. That will tell Excel to finish whatever is going on before taking on the next step. If that doesn't help, the next thing is to disect the macros

Comment: actually I did a bit of research on the topic, without the `doevents` part it will actually sort of multithread the macro wherever possible. two of my macros were actually reading/writing to and from the same cells, I think this was the reason of the crash.

Answer (score -1):

What probably is happening is that `oneclick` is not defined with a `Dim` statement, so by default its defined at procedure level, meaning if you set `oneclick` it to 0 in another `Sub`, your setting another local/procedure level variable, and your variable in `macro1` is unchanged, so your chain of macros never stops, which leads to a stack overflow/crash as stated in one of the comments above.

So either define `oneclick` as public variable (I recommend to define it as Boolean as it seems to basically be a switch .... True/False) or you pass the variable as argument down your chain of macros ( `Sub Macro2(ByRef oneclick as Boolean)` ).

All that said, as one of comments above stated, you can have all your chained subs in the main sub ( `macro1` ) as they will only get executed one after the other, e.g.

```
Sub macro1()
    Dim oneclick As Boolean

    oneclick = True         'Need to get set to true to start

    If oneclick Then Call macro2(oneclick)

    If oneclick Then Call macro3(oneclick)

    ........


End Sub

Sub macro2(ByRef oneclick As Boolean)

    oneclick = False            'One of your macros has to set oneclick to false to stop the chain/execution, probably under acondition

End Sub
```

Comment: I fail to see the logic in this.

Comment: i have a public variable already defined at project level. when I assign a value within a sub it's the public variable that changes. The same chain works with a simpler set of macros.

Comment: You did not share this info when you posted the question.  Would have appreciated you did.

Comment: well.. actually I wrote "So far I have been using this method: First I have a mini sub that assigns value=1 to the global variable "oneclick", and then calls the first macro of the chain". I didn't put it together with the rest, sorry if it confused you.